# Error: tunneling sucket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080 at clientRequest.onError <C:/program File/heruko/client

Tags: php, mysql, database, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a mysql database app on heroku and i need to login in to my account from the terminal but when i run

```
heroku login
```

it returns this error message

```
Error: tunneling sucket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080 

at clientRequest.onError <C:/program File/heruko/client/node_module/tunnel-agent/index.js:177:17>
```

i have deleted the environment variable `http_proxy` that could cause the error but still the same.

This error message comes up even if i want to update heroku with

```
heroku update
```

please what can i do?

Comment: _Suggestion:_ You can also just use `__DIR__` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Answer (score 0):

First argument of `define()` should be a string:

```
define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

Note, passing a constant is valid but defines the value of that constant as a consant (provided the value is valid constant name):

```
define('FOO', 'BAR');
define(FOO, 'BAZ');

// string(3) "BAZ"
var_dump(BAR);
```

Comment: How can i access variable ROOT_PATH  in another file?
I used 
<?PHP include(ROOT_PATH."/app/include/header.php"); ?>

I'm getting this error

Warning: include(ROOT_PATH/app/include/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\blog\single.php on line 22

Comment: Include the file containing this code using `require` or `require_once`. How and where exactly depends on your application's structure. On a basic web script this should be in any valid entry point (e.g. `index.php`). Once it's included, all other files included afterwards will have access to the constant.